# C#.Net get workingdirectory from fileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, execute, filedialog, working-directory

I have a filedialog in my application that gets the path of the file to execute, for example.

> C:\filespool\run.exe

Now I put this in a string variable called exepath and execute it with this code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
proc.Start();
```

You can see that I've set the workingdirectory but I dont know how to get it in the best way, so I ask people that know it here. How to get the workingdirectory "C:\filespool".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `FileInfo` object and reference its `DirectoryName` property.  You'll have to include the `System.IO` namespace.

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(exepath);
string path = f.DirectoryName;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directoryname.aspx)'s the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you need fully, but you can use [FileInfo.Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory.aspx) to get the directory of a file path.

Answer (score 1):

Try Directory.GetCurrentDirectory Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is one answer. It is something that can trip you up if you are not ready for it. After an open (or save) dialog box, Environment.CurrentDirectory changes to the directory of the dialog. So:

```
path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
exepath = dlg.FileName;
```